# How to display data from array of objects in a textbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I want to display data stored in an array in form-
 for example:

```
var users =
[
  { 
    'name':'John',
    'age':'10'
  },
  { 
    'name':'Rose',
    'age':'18'
  }
];
```

and I want to display name and age of users logged in, in the form below:

```
<form id="myform">
    <div>              
    </div> 
    <h2 align="center"> Edit Details</h2>
    <table id="table1"; cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="5%"; align="center">
       <tr>
              <td  align="right" class="style1">First Name:</td>
              <td class="style1"><input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="FirstName" /></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
              <td align="right">Last Name:</td>
              <td><input id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="LastName" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
              <td align="right">Email ID:</td>
              <td><input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
              <td align="right">User Name:</td>
              <td><input id="username" type="text" placeholder="UserName" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
              <td align="right">Password:</td>
              <td><input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="edit()" />
        <td> <input type="button" value="Reset" />       
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</form>
```

Comment: Read this before ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Here we can't create the code for you. Try to do it yourself, and then post the code if your code don't work and we will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I actually needed this..Well I do not expect any one to write codes for me, but yes, I could have asked this question in a better way. I tried this-- document.getElementById("input1").value=users[0].username; but its giving me error called 'cannot read property 'username' of undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the text content with pure javascript.

```
name.textContent = 'First name' + users[0].name;
```

Of course, you will need to select all the fields you want to change.